# Rigidbody container is spilling out contained rigidbodies

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to make a simulation where I have a container and it is getting filled with more rigid bodies (Soccerballs) falling from above. The container gets filled fine but when I try to animate the container itself from one location to another the contained Rigidbodies spill out from the containers sides ..

the soccerballs are relativly small in size, I don't know if this is the reason for the problem.

I have tried the following solutions but with no use, balls still spill out from the container.

1- I have changed the container collision shape sensitivity margin.
2- I have changed the balls collision shape(the problem got worse)
3- I have tried changing friction and bounciness of the balls

How can I solve this problem, what settings can I change that might help?

thanks in advance for your answers, I am sorry that the question got too long.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by slowing down the animation, I changed the movement of the container from 24 frames to 44 frames.. the problem was that the container is moving to fast.. I still want to know how to get the rigid bodies to stay contained while moving the container fast in the animation.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and mark it as resolved as to help others with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to complete the project without problem when I slowed down the movement of the rigid body container, I think that gave blender more time to be able to calculate the collision between the rigid bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Scene properties are the Rigid Body World settings. This includes a Steps Per Second property. This setting determines how often blender should check the position of objects in the scene for how they should interact - faster moving objects require a larger number of steps to prevent them passing through each other before Blender detects the collision.

Comment: Thanks Rich for your answer, unfortunately, I have tried the solution you have mentioned but it resulted in weird behavior from the rigid bodies.

Comment: @RaymondGabriel Another thing to try is to ensure the Scale of your object is “applied” by selecting them, pressing Ctrl+A and selecting Scale.